# Navigation Drawer RTL lang

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm Using Navigation Drawer in one  of my app activity it's open from left to right how i can change it to right to left and icon direction too
i try layout_gravity:right; but force closed happened during running app
i did not get my answer from other question 
app minimum SDK is set to 15

here is activity_main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
     >

    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is main activity

```
package ir.diamonddesign.tajrobi96;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);


    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.homeitem) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);

        } else if (id == R.id.questionitem) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Questionsactivity.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        } else if (id == R.id.answeritem) {

        } else if (id == R.id.eduitem) {

        } else if (id == R.id.sourceitem) {

        } else if (id == R.id.changeitem) {

        } else if (id == R.id.videositem) {

        } else if (id == R.id.newsitem) {

        } else if (id == R.id.shareitem) {

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = "اینو ببین : https://cafebazaar.ir/app/ir.tik.tik/?l=fa";
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "موضوع پیام");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "از طریق"));

        } else if (id == R.id.contactitem) {



            String[] TO = {"tajrobi@tinytree.ml"};

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "موضوع پیام");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"سلام از اپیکیشن کنکور تماس میگیرم....");
            startActivity(emailIntent);




        }



        else if (id == R.id.exititem) {
finish();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MikeM. No I Using minSdkVersion 15 any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It will be automatically changed to RTL when you change the Locale of your application.